# Translate plugin without using translation plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, translate

I'm developing a job onepager template that we can sell to new clients. I'm using a plugin to add the jobs, but the application form is in English while I want to set the text to Dutch.

Is there a way to translate some elements from a plugin (which is made translate-ready) without a translation plugin like WPML? I want to make this template as lightweight as possible and since the sites will only be in Dutch, I also don's need a plugin for this

Edit: I'm using the WP Job Openings plugin

Comment: Can you edit the label of the from via your wordpress console ?

Comment: No I can't edit the form labels or fields. I located the file that contains the form logic, but I don't want to change the file directly in the plugin to prevent problems when I update the plugin.

Comment: Can you add more information about the form plugin you are using ?

Comment: I just added the plugin name

Comment: You might need to translate it yourself. You can get more information [here](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/wp-job-openings/) and [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-openings/#developers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Jquery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("label[for='awsm-applicant-name']").html("Naam");
   $("input[type='submit']").val("Solliciteer");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="awsm-job-form-group">
<label for="awsm-applicant-name">Full Name <span class="awsm-job-form-error">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="awsm_applicant_name" class="awsm-job-form-field awsm-job-form-control" id="awsm-applicant-name" required="" data-msg-required="This field is required." aria-required="true">
</div>
<div class="awsm-job-form-group">
<input type="submit" name="form_sub" id="awsm-application-submit-btn" value="Submit" data-response-text="Submittin">
</div>
```

**Edit:**

To change the submit value in this form you could use:

```
$("input[type='submit']").val("Solliciteer");
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Bedankt!

Comment: Can I do the same with this element?:<input type="submit" name="form_sub" id="awsm-application-submit-btn" value="Submit" data-response-text="Submitting..">

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the submit button value change

Comment: Keep in mind, that the plugin might use this input value to execute its logic. In that case, you might want to look at a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

PRO addon of WP Job Openings comes with a form builder. You can change the labels and everything using the form builder interface.

Comment: Hi, Aravind. Congrats on your first answer, however, this seems more like a comment than solution.